# How to consume the SAP Web serveices in Android

Tags: android, sup, sap-gateway, sap-smp

I want to build mobile apps for smartphones which will get data content from our SAP Backend.
I have experience in developing native Android apps but with SAP, I will get my first question in mind that "Where do I have to start ?".

I researched and get heard so many terms about SUP, Netweaver Gateway, OData, UI5, Cordova, Eclipse and so on.
And now I'm confused, I want at first really understand only which way I have to go.

Can you tell me the routes in which way I have to walk if I want to develop native apps or non-native apps which are communicate basically with my SAP backend.

Logically I can populate my RFC's as Webservices and I can communicate with them but I want to get the standard way, which is described by SAP with the terms I mentioned at start (SUP, Gateway, OData....)

And why is always eclipse used in tutorials? Is eclipse the developer platform for non native apps which is chosed by the contributers ?

Additionally what I want to know too is about the license, can I develop apps for free or do I have to pay a fee for the development tools, mentioned above ?

I know I have so much questions, but how I said, I'm a newbie in mobile apps on SAP and so much terms are confusing. So please understand me and help me out of these situation.

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

It is a broad topic that requires a broad anwer, I am doing the same thing, 
so I will share my experience so far:

You must install the SMP SDK on a server, with its Eclipse workspace.
In here you will create MBOs, mobile bussiness objects, that filter data out
off incoming sap webservices. (I can read and filter data from these W.services so far)

The next step is to deploy these MBOs to the server and generate a bunch of classes that you
will then need to import to your App project in your good old eclipse IDE.

Next... you must connect and synchronize your app to read the data from the SMP, by calling mehtods from the classes you imported before. This is where I cant make it work because the possibiliities 
of IP addresses ports and what not has gotten to broad, and I have'nt been able to establish a connection between my app and the SMP.

In general it is a very painful experience, and there is little useful info online, 
I thought that android was a bit tricky to handle but SAP's SMP is far more frustrating.
I am doing it by myself but I am already searching for help.